# docker systemd: how i can automatically start a container while setting up a service in systemd (BASH)

Tags: bash, docker, scripting, containers, systemd

I will run a docker container with the command
`docker run -ti --rm -p 8080:80 -v $(pwd)/my/path/to/config myimage:latest` 
but the plan is to write a function in a script, that start these image, while starting the VM in systemd.
Do I have to set up a service in /lib/systemd/system ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docker website's documentation,

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

You can use a restart policy, and parameters are,

Use a restart policy
To configure the restart policy for a container, use the --restart flag when using the docker run command. The value of the --restart flag can be any of the following:

`Flag` 
Description

`no` 
Do not automatically restart the container. (the default)

`on-failure` 
Restart the container if it exits due to an error, which manifests as a non-zero exit code.

`always` 
Always restart the container if it stops. If it is manually stopped, it is restarted only when Docker daemon restarts or the container itself is manually restarted. (See the second bullet listed in restart policy details)

`unless-stopped` 
Similar to always, except that when the container is stopped (manually or otherwise), it is not restarted even after Docker daemon restarts.

If these do not work for your requirements, then there is information about you can use a process manager such as upstart, systemd, or supervisor lower down the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Dockerfile`, add at the last

`ENTRYPOINT service ssh restart && bash`

Comment: and that means? when I start the build the container will be startet automatically?